# Searching items stored with async storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of items displayed in a flat list (card)  stored using async storage that I would like to search using a search bar, I get the data for items (stored in async storage) from **this. state. saved** like you can see in the code bellow

for some reason my approach doesn't work and I can't understand why? I apologize for the long code any help would be much appreciated

```
class SaveSearchList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      temp: [],
      error: null,
      search: null,
      saved: [],
    };
  }
  removeItem = () => {
    DeleteItem("saved")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          saved: [],
        });
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getData();
    this.readItems();
    this.unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      "focus",
      this.readItems
    );
  };
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }
  readItems = () => {
    ReadItem("saved")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          const saved = JSON.parse(res);
          this.setState({
            saved: saved,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => console.warn(e));
  };
  getData = async () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    try {
      this.setResult(this.state.saved);
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({ error: "Error Loading content", loading: false });
    }
  };
  setResult = (res) => {
    this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.data, ...res],
      temp: [...this.state.temp, ...res],
      error: res.error || null,
      loading: false,
    });
  };

  renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: colors.shade2,
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textAlign: "center",
          }}
        >
          Browse Saved Articles
        </Text>
        <SearchBar
          containerStyle={{
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 5,
            borderColor: "#353540",
            borderTopColor: "#353540",
            borderBottomColor: "#353540",
          }}
          inputContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: colors.shade1 }}
          round
          showLoading
          placeholder="Search for articles"
          onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
          value={this.state.search}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  updateSearch = (search) => {
    this.setState({ search }, () => {
      if ("" == search) {
        this.setState({
          data: [...this.state.temp],
        });
        return;
      }

      this.state.data = this.state.temp
        .filter(function (item) {
          return item.title.includes(search);
        })
        .map(function ({ id, title, category, img, content }) {
          return { id, title, category, img, content };
        });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return this.state.error != null ? (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Text>{this.state.error}</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            console.log("nothing");
          }}
          title="Reload"
        />
      </View>
    ) : (
      <View style={{ top: 50 }}>
        <FlatList
          style={{}}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          data={this.state.saved}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <TouchableScale
                activeScale={0.9}
                tension={50}
                friction={7}
                useNativeDriver
                onPress={() =>
                  this.props.navigation.navigate("DetailScreen", {
                    data: item,
                  })
                }
              >
                <View style={{ left: 10, top: 20 }}>
                  <Card item={item} />
                </View>
              </TouchableScale>
            );
          }}
        />
        <View style={styles.button}>
          {this.state.saved.length > 0 && (
            <AppButton
              title="Remove Key"
              color="secondary"
              onPress={this.removeItem}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    top: 20,
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    alignItems: "center",
    left: 40,
  },
});
export default SaveSearchList;
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does to async storage works? Did you try to console.log "ReadItem"?

Comment: hello thank you for your response , yes async storage works perfectly but the search doesn't when i search anything i get nothing , also the same aproach i used for search was working perfectly  with data from an end point

Comment: Flatlist data should not be equal to "this.state.data" instead of "this.state.saved"?

Comment: am not sure i understand what do you mean the flatlist data is equal indeed to this.state.saved

Comment: I added an answer to be clearer. Hopefully it will help you solve you this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right you are loading all saved items and then you want to filter them using search text (that only items that relevant to search will appear).

The problem is that changing the searchbar text changed "this.state.data" while the flatlist data is "this.state.saved", which is not being changed following the search text changes.

To be more clear I am adding the piece of code I think should be changed.

**Current:**

```
updateSearch = (search) => {
    this.setState({ search }, () => {
      if ("" == search) {
        this.setState({
          data: [...this.state.temp],
        });
        return;
      }

      this.state.data = this.state.temp
        .filter(function (item) {
          return item.title.includes(search);
        })
        .map(function ({ id, title, category, img, content }) {
          return { id, title, category, img, content };
        });
    });
  };
```

and

```
...
...
  <FlatList
      style={{}}
      ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
      data={this.state.saved}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <TouchableScale
            activeScale={0.9}
            tension={50}
            friction={7}
 ...
 ...
```

**Change to:**

```
updateSearch = (search) => {
    this.setState({ search }, () => {
      if ("" == search) {
        this.setState({
          data: [...this.state.temp],
        });
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ data: this.state.temp
        .filter(function (item) {
          return item.title.includes(search);
        })
        .map(function ({ id, title, category, img, content }) {
          return { id, title, category, img, content };
        });
    });
  };
```

and

```
...
...
  <FlatList
      style={{}}
      ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
      data={this.state.data}                   <------------- CHANGED --------
      keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <TouchableScale
            activeScale={0.9}
            tension={50}
            friction={7}
 ...
 ...
```

and

```
readItems = () => {
    ReadItem("saved")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          const saved = JSON.parse(res);
          this.setState({
            saved: saved, temp: saved, data: saved          //  <---------- CHANGED ----
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => console.warn(e));
  };
```

Comment: thank you for your anwser , changing this.state.saved to this.state.data made the saved items using async storage not be displayed using the flatlist and the search still doesn't work for some reason

Comment: I added another piece of code I think should be changed.

Comment: Thank you for your response and your help , its working perfectly now just getting a key has to be unique warning for some reason

Comment: My pleasure. Can you elaborate about the warning? which row it refers to?

Comment: yes apprently the warning was cause of saving the same item with async storage ( generates two duplicates keys ) any idea why async sotrage execpts the saving of same values ?